# Relatively pick X values out of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to pick X values relatively out of an Array. For example I'd like to pick 4 values out of the following array:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

what I am doing now is:

```
var newArr = [];
var pick = 4;
var delta = arr.length/pick;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + delta) {
    k = Math.floor(i);
    newArr.push(arr[k]);
};

// then I'm cheating a bit
newarr[newArr.length-1] = arr[newArr.length-1];
```

My problem is, at some values (I'm using this on longer arrays) the new array is longer than the defined pick variable. This has to do with the delta and the following rounding, who fit an additional value sometimes.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly? The expected result should be one of these:

```
newArr = [1,3,6,9] || newArr = [1,4,6,9] || newArr = [1,4,7,9]
```

Comment: `The expected result should be one of these` ... which one? why not check `newarr.length <= pick` in the for loop

Comment: to be honest I can't see how you could expect any of those ... your code should, and does, result in `newArr == [1,3,5,7]`

Comment: It is not possible that your new array is longer than the original, as your `for` loop iterates *n* times exactly, so there will be that many elements in new array.

Comment: @JaromandaX i know, atually I'm a bit cheating right now. (I updated my example correctly). What I would like to achieve is to get the values distributed on the whole original array.

Comment: This might be what you're trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451298/evenly-select-n-elems-from-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is in this line:

```
var delta = arr.length/pick;
```

With this value of *delta* you will make *i* arrive at the value `arr.length` at the last iteration of the loop, which is not a valid index. It should arrive (according to your request) at the last element of the array. Also, you want to start with the first value as well, and so your delta should be bigger (the interval is determined by *pick-1* parts), and so the above statement should be:

```
if (pick == 1) return [arr[0]]; // exceptional case
var delta = (arr.length-1)/(pick-1);
```

To deal with floating point inaccuracies, you should better use `round` than `floor`, so that if at the last iteration the value of *i* is a tiny fraction below `arr.length-1` it will still target that index.

To be absolutely sure you generate the desired number of values, you should make that count your loop condition.

Finally, you seem to want to also start with the first value in the array, so that means you should not add the delta to your *i* value until after you picked the first value.

Taken all this together you could arrive at this function:

```js
function pickFrom(arr, pick) {
  if (pick == 1) return [arr[0]]; // exceptional case
  var newArr = [];
  var delta = (arr.length-1)/(pick-1);
  var k, i = 0;

  while (pick--) {
    k = Math.round(i);
    newArr.push(arr[k]);
    i = i + delta;
  }
  return newArr;
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var res = pickFrom(arr, 4);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NB: always use `var` (or `const`, `let`) to define your variables.

#### Alternative code

Here is a concise ES6 function that achieves the same:

```js
function pickFrom(arr, pick) {
  var delta = (arr.length-1)/Math.max(1, pick-1);
  return Array.from(Array(pick), (_, i) => arr[Math.round(i*delta)])
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var res = pickFrom(arr, 4);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: do you know what this is called? I didn't know how to search for this function. Is it some kind of mapping or how would you call it?

Comment: You're welcome. I think with terms like *"evenly spaced"* you'll find some similar questions. :-) Here are a few: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2451363/5459839), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2451363/5459839), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9365303/5459839).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use only the counter looping from zero to `pick` and do the multiplication for every element and get the index of the integer value of the calculation.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    newArr = [],
    pick = 4,
    delta = arr.length / pick,
    i = 0;

while (i < pick) {
    newArr.push(arr[Math.floor(i * delta)]);
    i++;
}

console.log(newArr);
```